# Iphone App for Collaborating on planning a long vacation togather

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, mobile-apps

I am planning a very important and relatively longer trip with my partner.
My Partner and I both have Iphones. I would like to use an app that allows us to

- Provides a checklist and the ability to check things of the list
- Build our itinerary
- Share places we would like to visit during the trip
- Ability to share any related articles and store them
- Bonus if we can journal in the app itself during or after our trip

Tripit would not work for us since it does not do the checklist part.

Comment: Google Docs/Google Spreadsheets? (Or OneNote + Excel if you're a Microsoft person)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use two tools together when I want to plan trips with someone (or solo):

The first is [TripIt](https://www.tripit.com/), which you're already familiar with. I use it to track our itinerary and any confirmed reservations. Planes, trains, hotels, restaurant reservations, tours, sporting events, anything where I'm planning to do something at a certain date and time goes into the TripIt itinterary.

The other tool I use is [Evernote](https://evernote.com/). I'll create one or more notebooks for the trip and tag entries with the name of the relevant city or area. Evernote allows you to create [checklists](https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2011/08/02/did-you-know-how-to-create-a-checklist-in-evernote/) and lets you share your notebooks with your travel companions. You can clip web pages for places you may want to visit, even geotag them and place them on a map. You could set aside a notebook as a collaborative journal as well. The free plan would cover most usage as long as you don't save large files, but the $25/year plan is cheap and lets you download your notebooks for [offline use](https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2015/01/26/configure-offline-notebooks/).

This lets me keep TripIt focused on things I "have" to do, while having a notebook of places and articles of interest at hand in Evernote when I'm deciding what I "want" to do each day. While it's possible some tool would combine these two, separating your reserved itinerary from your notes is fairly useful.